# Find out whether tcp port is bound (not listening) using bash

Tags: linux, bash, sockets, tcp

I am trying to determine whether a TCP port that was bound by a process, that was recently started, is actually in use by that particular process.

Take this **program.cpp**

```
int daemonport = 11234;

struct sockaddr_in loopback;
memset ((char*) &loopback, 0, sizeof (loopback));
socklen_t len = sizeof (loopback);
loopback.sin_family = AF_INET;
loopback.sin_port = htons (daemonport);
loopback.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_LOOPBACK);
daemonfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (daemonfd < 0)
{
    errx (EXIT_FAILURE, "Critical error");
}
if (bind (daemonfd, (struct sockaddr*) &loopback, sizeof (loopback)) != 0)
{
    errx (EXIT_FAILURE, "Daemon already running, TCP port: '%d'", daemonport);
}
if (getsockname (daemonfd, (struct sockaddr*) &loopback, &len) != 0)
{
    errx (EXIT_FAILURE, "Critical error");
}
printf ("%d\n", ntohs (loopback.sin_port));

if (daemon (1, 0) < 0)
{
    close (daemonfd);
    errx (EXIT_FAILURE, "Failed to daemonize!");
}

// event loop...

close (daemonfd);
```

Now with the tcp socket bound (but not listening) to port 11234 I want to check whether the port is bound by the process using a bash script.

I tried various netstat and lsof patterns w/o success:

`netstat -a | grep ':11234'` as well as `lsof -i :11234`.

They all don't print a line with the bound port.

But when I try to run the program a 2nd time it errors out with:

```
Daemon already running, TCP port: '11234'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Linux, start with this:

`netstat --inet -n -a -p | grep ':myport'`

and see what you're getting.  The `--inet` keeps from showing IP6 and Unix domain sockets.  `-n` shows numerical results and not names translated from the port number.  `-p` tells you which process is listening on it.

If any of those lines lay "LISTEN" then a process is lisening on that port.  However, *any* open connections using that port (even "TIME_WAIT") will prevent the port from being re-opened unless you use the [SO_REUSEPORT option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t) every time you bind to it.

If that command isn't showing you anything then nothing is listening on that port which means there must be a problem with your program.

You're printing an error message but assuming the problem is something already running.  Print out the `errno` value (use `perror(...)`) so you can exactly what the problem is.

Comment: If I add `perror(...)` for the bind error check it prints `Address already in use` as expected. That is when I try to run the program while another instance of it is already bound to the port. `netstat --inet -n -a -p | grep ':11234'` doesn't show anything apart from the usual info for not being root.

Comment: If something is using the port, `netstat` will show it.  If you've recently run your program, used it, exited, and now it won't run again, it's an SO_REUSE problem.

Comment: The point is that the program is still running and therefore the socket ain't closed and a 2nd instance fails to bind to the same port which is exactly what I want to achieve. However, `netstat` does not show me the program associated with that port. `SO_REUSEPORT` does not seem to be available on my debian os. If I set `SO_REUSEADDR` instead the 2nd instance won't error out at bind which makes sense but it not what I want.

Comment: As a matter of fact: As soon as I terminate the first instance the socket gets closed and once I run the program again it doesn't error out. The thing I am saying is that the port binding does seem to work as it should.

Comment: All sockets will get closed when your program exits but that doesn't mean they cease to exist.  TCP will go through its shut-down phase which often includes a couple minutes of "TIME_WAIT" for previously established connections during which the port number is still "in use" (unless you use SO_REUSEPORT) when trying to bind to it again.

Answer (score 0):

By way of example, to check to see if port 56789 is available locally:

```
port=56789
retval=$(python3 -c 'import socket; s=socket.socket(); s.bind(("", '"${port}"')); print(s.getsockname()[1]); s.close()' 2>/dev/null)
echo "$retval"
```

This will print a blank line if the port is already bound, and will print 56789 if it is not bound. If port 56789 was recently used and closed, but the TIME_WAIT period has not yet elapsed (typically one or two minutes), then the port will not be available and the above code will not echo 56789.

I realize that this is a bit of a cheat, because it also uses python, but it is bash scriptable if python 3 is available. No sudo required.